# Auto-populate Calendar App after Leave Request has been approved flow

Tags: sharepoint-calendar, flow

So I created a Leave Request and used Flows as it was easier to automate it. Now I want to link it to Calendar (SharePoint App) so that the calendar is auto-populated once a request has been approved. I tried to add more actions/conditions to my Flow, but just ended messing it up and had to re-build from scratch. This is what my Flow looks like:
[image: Flow]
[image: flow]

Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement, I understand that you have to create an item in Calendar list after leave request has been approved.

Below the condition logic in the IF YES block, you can add an action "create item" after the send an email action. You cab refer my action created for different requirement but it will work for you as well.
[image]

The final flow should look like as below. This totally matches your scenario.[image]

Comment: Thanks, it worked like a charm :) But I have one more issue. When item is created in Calendar it is always one day short. Any idea? I am not sure if I can just add +1 day to End Date field.

Comment: I think that might be time zone issue.  Send me what is your end time I will test in my flow. Mark as answer if it solves your problem it will help others to refer.